# Does wxWidgets have something comparable to Qt's MFC Migration framework?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, wxwidgets, qt-mfc-migration

I want to build a DLL plugin for a 3rd party MFC-based application.   The "official" way to do this is to build the plugin using MFC as well.  I'm looking to see if it's possible to use any other gui toolkits to ease my development.  I've played around with Qt's MFC Migration Framework (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/) for which I have had some success but I've run into a road block with it.  Now I'm considering alternatives.  Does wxWidgets have any support for building a DLL that will integrate with an MFC host application?

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is no need to build a plugin using MFC even if the main application does use it so I'm not sure what are your exact requirements. All I can say is that it is possible to use wxWidgets and MFC together as the `mfc` sample included in wxWidgets distribution shows. But it's still better to avoid mixing two different frameworks if you can.

Comment: From the Qt perspective, I believe the reason for the Qt/MFC migration framework has to do with the event loops.  Qt has it's own event loop and so does the hosted MFC application.  Having two event loops I believe is problematic so the Qtwinmigrate project does something to merge the two event loops.